# Replace string with other string in Lua

Tags: lua

Good evening,

I am currently editing a Scoarboard in Lua and there are loaded by a GroupManager of the groups without formatting. These must now be formatted.

Example:
Current Rank: "superadmin"
Goal: "Super Admin"

```
func = function(ply) return ply:GetUserGroup() end
```

This funktion returns the groupname "superadmin" but now i don't have no idea

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to map from lower case words to upper case without knowing where to break words, you can create a table with all the possible combinations that you want to convert. For example:

```
local convtable = {
  superadmin = "Super Admin",
  somethingelse = "Something Else",
}
func = function(ply)
  local group = ply:GetUserGroup()
  return convtable[group] or group
end
```

This will return the converted text or the original string if it's not present in the mapping.

Comment: _it's not possible to map from lower case words to upper case without knowing where to break words_ - indeed!  Example: `superbass` :-)